# Repeater link button with image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

No response... Is it because my explanation is not clear..?

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="Maroon">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

My code for link button for edit is as above.when click it will disappear and show update and cancel link buttons and if cancel is clicked Edit link button will shown again.This is working fine.

But when I add an image in my link button as below, Image is showing with the button and when link button is clicked Edit link button is not showing and the update and cancel link buttons are showing.Until this is fine.
**But when I click cancel link button Edit link button is showing as a single line with out any text or image**( after adding the image to the Edit link button)

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Maroon">Edit
 <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="editb2.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" />
  </asp:LinkButton>
```

above is my repeater's link button with an image and below code is repeater1.itemCommand

```
 Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand

  If e.CommandName = "cancel" Then
  DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lnkEdit"), LinkButton).Visible = True

  End if
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you press cancel the below event is executed.In that make the Edit index=-1 then it displays as it was before.

```
 Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    grdCustomers.EditIndex = -1
 End Sub
```

If it is an Repeater check the command name

```
if (e.CommandName == "cancel")
    {
        ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtn")).Visible = true;
    }
```